# C++ cant exit while loop

Tags: c++, vector, while-loop, switch-statement

So for my program of manipulating a vector, a choice is presented at the end of each switch case: If the letter `'q'` is entered, the program is supposed to exit the while loop and end the program, but when I enter the letter `'q'`, the program crashes instead of exiting properly. Why is this happening? Is it an infinite loop?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int rnum;
    int jnum;
    int i;
    int lim = 5;
    char choice='b';
    vector<int> jersey(lim);
    vector<int> rating(lim);

    cout << "MENU" << endl;
    cout << "a - Add player" << endl;
    cout << "d - Remove player" << endl;
    cout << "u - Update player rating" << endl;
    cout << "r - Output players above a rating" << endl;
    cout << "o - Output roster" << endl;
    cout << "q - Quit" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Choose an option:" << endl;

    cin >> choice;

    while(choice != 'q') {

        switch(choice) {

        case 'a' :
            // addplayer
            for(int i = 0; i<=lim-1; i++)
            {
                cout << "Enter a new player's jersey number:" << endl;
                cin >> jersey.at(i);
                cout <<"Enter the player's rating:" << endl;
                cin >> rating.at(i);

            }

            cout << "Choose an option:" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
        break;

       case 'u' :
            // updat rating
            cout << "Enter a jersey number:" << endl;
            cin >> jnum;

            for( int i = 0; i <= lim-1; i++ )
            {
                if( jersey.at(i) == jnum )
                {
                    cout << "Enter a new rating for player:" <<endl;
                    cin >> rnum;
                    rating.at(i) = rnum;

                    break;
                }
            }

            cout << "Choose an option:" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
        break;

       case 'o':
            cout << "ROSTER" << endl;
            for(int i = 0; i<lim; i++)
            {
                cout << "Player "<<i+1 <<" -- Jersey number:" << " " <<jersey.at(i) << ", " << "Rating: " << rating.at(i) << endl;
            }

            cout << "Choose an option:" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
        break;

        case 'd':
            cout << "Enter a jersey number:" << endl;
            cin >> jnum;

            for( std::vector<int>::iterator spot = jersey.begin(); spot != jersey.end(); ++spot )
            {
                if( *spot == jnum )
                {
                    jersey.erase( spot );
                    rating.erase( spot );
                    lim = jersey.size();
                }
            }

            cout << "Choose an option:" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
        break;

        case 'r':
            cout << "Enter a rating:" << endl;
            cin >> rnum;

            for( int i = 0; i <= lim-1; i++ )
            {
                if( rating.at(i) >= rnum )
                {
                    cout << "Player "<<i+1 <<" -- Jersey number:" << " " <<jersey.at(i) << ", " << "Rating: " << rating.at(i) << endl;
                }
            }

            cout << "Choose an option:" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
        break;


        default:
            cout << "Choose an option:" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
        break;

        }
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The best tool for this is your debugger...

Comment: Have you considered formatting your code so it's readable?

Comment: Your formatting is going to trip you up. As it is, I see no error. You are misusing vectors as if they were simple arrays... What do you mean by “the program crashes instead of exiting properly”? (That, or give us some exact input that replicates the failure.)

Comment: First, move the input out of each switch case and put it at the end. There's no reason to repeat it so many times.  I tested your program by pressing o then q, it exited normally. You'll need to be more specific about what you're doing.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Apologize for the formatting, it seems that im still pretty bad at it, thought I was doing it right but i guess i need to pay attention  and look up a tutorial. concerning the programming, i did what you said, put the input at the end, but the same result happens. what i did is I first  entered the values into the vector with the a option, then i deleted one of the elements with the d option, then i quit  out with q. but q didn't exit properly, another debugger said it was an infinite loop. can you try this and see if you get the same result?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yep, I've tested it a lot more, and the problem is somewhere within the 'd' case.just don't know what at the moment.

Comment: Formatting could be better.  What is the sequence of options you selected before you selected 'q'?  I tried a couple of sequences and its quitting the application fine, i.e. no crash.

Answer (score 0):

Your `case 'd'` looks incorrect. You can't use `spot` to erase an element from `rating` since `spot` only iterates over `jersey`'s elements. To fix this, and potentially solve your crash or infinite loop issue, you can replace the following code:

```
if( *spot == jnum )
{
    jersey.erase( spot );
    rating.erase( spot );
    lim = jersey.size();
}
```

With:

```
if( *spot == jnum )
{
    jersey.erase( spot );
    rating.erase( rating.begin() + (spot - jersey.begin()) );
    lim = jersey.size();
}
```

Here, `spot - jersey.begin()` will give you the index of the jersey you just found, adding that to `rating.begin()` will therefore give you the corresponding rating and allow you to properly erase it from the `rating` vector.

In addition, since your code allows duplicate jersey numbers, deleting a duplicate won't always delete all instances of the number. If you want to fix this, you can add `spot--;` after `lim = jersey.size();` to ensure you don't skip over duplicate elements.